# Output is same title all over again

Tags: c#, selenium, web-scraping

my code supposed to print the titles, of each `elem` in `elements`, but instead it write only the first `elem` title

I've tried to print each `elem` in `elements`, and it successfully show the whole 20 different element ids, but the `titlex` is printing only the first book title 20 times, also tried to put the `foreach` loop of printing to console out of the `for` loop, but still getting same output!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using System.Threading;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;  

namespace book_scraper_2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    /// 

    public class Book
    {

        public string Titlex { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
        public string Rate { get; set; }


    }
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        readonly IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        string user_url;
        public void Scrape() {
            var books = new List<Book>();
            user_url = Text1.Text;
            int.TryParse(Text2.Text, out var x);
            for (int i =1; i < x; i ++) {
                driver.Url = "http://" + user_url + "/catalogue/" + "page-" + i + ".html";
                var elements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//article[@class='product_pod']"));
                    foreach (var elem in elements) {
                        books.Add(new Book
                        {
                            Titlex = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//h3/a")).Text,
                            Price = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//p[@class='price_color']")).Text,
                            Rate = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//article/p")).GetAttribute("class")?.Replace("star-rating ", "")
                        });

                
                    }
            foreach (var a in books) {

                Console.WriteLine($"{a.Titlex}");

            }

        }


        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Scrape();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm expecting to see the title of all the books in the site

Note:website used is `books.toscrape.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason **You are getting the same Title is that you are accessing the same driver in the `foreach` loop**,

I took the part of the `foreach` loop and made the correction, which is accessing the current element in the `foreach` loop

```
var elements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//article[@class='product_pod']"));
foreach (var elem in elements) {
    books.Add(new Book
        {
            Titlex = elem.FindElement(By.XPath("//h3/a")).Text,
            Price = elem.FindElement(By.XPath("//p[@class='price_color']")).Text,
            Rate = elem.FindElement(By.XPath("//article/p")).GetAttribute("class")?.Replace("star-rating ", "")
        });
}
```

Comment: I fixed that and used elem instead of driver, but still adding first elem values only to book over and over again, check it using a breakpoint it seems like moving from elem to another but in book it saves only the first value still

Comment: I needed to change the locators from global // to ./